# How to derive Infinitesimal Strain Tensor in Cylindrical Coordinates

Tags: tensor-calculus, mathematics, solid-mechanics

How can  I obtain the below formulas of infinitesimal strain in cylindrical coordinates using matrix calculation given the first formula? I find it hard to study them because I still don't know how to derive them.

$$
\epsilon_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}\left(u\otimes\nabla+\nabla\otimes u\right)\\
\,\\
\begin{align}
u\otimes\nabla
&=\begin{bmatrix}u_r\\u_{\vartheta}\\u_z\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}&\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\vartheta}&\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\end{bmatrix}\\\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial U_r}{\partial r}&\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial U_r}{\partial\vartheta}&\dfrac{\partial U_r}{\partial z}\\\\\dfrac{\partial U_{\vartheta}}{\partial r}&\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial U_{\vartheta}}{\partial\vartheta}&\dfrac{\partial U_{\vartheta}}{\partial z}\\\\\dfrac{\partial U_z}{\partial r}&\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial U_z}{\partial\vartheta}&\dfrac{\partial U_z}{\partial z}\end{bmatrix}\end{align}
$$

Above, I show my try in deriving the first part of the tensor, but I didn't know how to derive the second part.

\begin{align}
     \varepsilon_{ij} &= \frac{1}{2} (U_{i,j} + U_{j,i})\\
    \varepsilon_{rr} & = \cfrac{\partial u_r}{\partial r} \\
    \varepsilon_{\theta\theta} & = \cfrac{1}{r}\left(\cfrac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial \theta} + u_r\right) \\
    \varepsilon_{zz} & = \cfrac{\partial u_z}{\partial z} \\
    \varepsilon_{r\theta} & = \cfrac{1}{2}\left(\cfrac{1}{r}\cfrac{\partial u_r}{\partial \theta} + \cfrac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial r}- \cfrac{u_\theta}{r}\right) \\
    \varepsilon_{\theta z} & = \cfrac{1}{2}\left(\cfrac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial z} + \cfrac{1}{r}\cfrac{\partial u_z}{\partial \theta}\right) \\
    \varepsilon_{zr} & = \cfrac{1}{2}\left(\cfrac{\partial u_r}{\partial z} + \cfrac{\partial u_z}{\partial r}\right) 
  \end{align}

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: It is not a homework... I just have a well known formula used in all textbooks of continuum mechanics but I'm not finding its derivation.....

Comment: The [tag:homework-and-exercises]-tag does not only apply to actual homework assignments, but also to homework-_like_ questions. Please show what you have tried so far or if there is a specific step or concept that you are having troubles with.

Comment: I have edited my question........

Comment: The first line in your formula $\varepsilon_{ij}=(1/2)(U_{i,j}+U_{j,i})= (1/2)(\partial_j U_I+ \partial_j U_)j$ applies only to *Cartesian coordinates*, unless by the comma you mean the covariant derivative.

Comment: Ah okay. sorry I didn't know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te strain is not defined by a simple adaptation of the cartesian formula. The essential tool is the [*Lie derivative*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative#Examples).

In a coordinate system with metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ the strain due to an infinitesimal displacement $\eta^\mu$ is
$$
e_{\mu\nu} =\frac 12 ( \eta^\alpha \partial_\alpha g_{\mu\nu}+ g_{\mu \alpha}\partial_\nu \eta^\alpha + g_{\alpha \nu}\partial_\nu \eta^{\alpha})\\
\equiv \frac 12 [{\mathcal L}_\eta g]_{\mu\nu}
$$
when $g_{\mu\nu}=\delta_{\mu\nu}$ this reduces to the Cartsian expression.

You can also write
$$ 
[{\mathcal L}_\eta g]_{\mu\nu}= \nabla_\mu \eta_\nu+ \nabla_\nu \eta_\mu
$$
where the $\nabla_\mu$ are the covariant derivatives in your chosen coordinates.

Comment: I haven't mentioned anything about Cartesian coordinates. I just like to know the derivation of it in cylindrical coordinates

Comment: In other words, the mentioned formulas in my question, I'm sorry but you have confused me more

Comment: The first line in your formula $\varepsilon_{ij}=(1/2)(U_{i,j}+U_{j,i})= (1/2)(\partial_j U_I+ \partial_j U_j)$ applies only to *Cartesian coordinates*, unless by the comma you mean the covariant derivative. Try Googling strain and Lie derivative

Comment: Here is a pedagogical account of the derivation for spherical polars: Linear strain tensor and differential geometry
E. de Prunelé, https://doi.org/10.1119/1.2750376

Comment: I thought my question was simple. Now it is easier for me to just study them as they are or just wait for someone to continue my derivation

Comment: I wish science didn't require Math